# nvidia-prime needs reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, 18.04

I just got my second laptop with Nvidia Optimus. It's installed with Ubuntu 18.04 beta, Linux 4.15, Nvidia 390.48. The GPU is a Quadro M2200.

On my previous laptop, I could switch between the GPUs using `prime-select` then logout, login and enjoy.

Now, `prime-select` triggers `update-initramfs` and `update-grub`, seems to recompile the DKMS module, and I need to reboot in order to get the modifications. That's long and annoying.

Is there some mean to avoid a full reboot ?

I already tried with no success:

1. Log in through GDM
2. Run prime-select
3. Run systemctl restart display-manager
4. Log in again

(source : [Log off doesn't work, but reboot does on 375, Quadro M1000M, Dell Precision 550 | NVIDIA Developer Forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1001621/prime-select-nvidia-gt-log-off-doesn-t-work-but-reboot-does-on-375-quadro-m1000m-dell-precision-550/?offset=25))

My nvidia-bug-report.sh output : https://gist.github.com/aurelienpierre/1f892ce060e0ea70f6a7b276c66ce255

Comment: This still happens in the final 18.04 release - and it even happens in Ubuntu 17.10 - the problem is GDM. use lightDM instead, and a simple logout/login would suffice (at least when using prime indicator plus).

Comment: For 17.10, the problem was GDM - but for 18.04, it seems that a new method for prime-select is employed which requires a reboot. prime-switch 0.8.5 requires logout/login, while prime-switch 0.8.6 and onward required boot. Seems like it'd be better to revert to 16.04 until this thing is sorted if you'd like to easily switch between intel and nvidia GPUs. It may be a result of the move to kernel 4.15, as even from nvidia-settings switching GPUs on 18.04 requires a reboot while on 17.10 it does not (with the same revision of nvidia390 on both).

Comment: My best effort at fix is https://github.com/timrichardson/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04 which uses bbswitch, the old method.